# why can't I use create_or_update?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

It's unclear to me why this isn't working:

```
class FastGrowers < ActiveRecord::Base  
end 
FastGrowers.create_or_update(:id => t.id, :ticker => ticker, :five_year_growth_rate => growth_rate)
```

I get this as a result:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined method `create_or_update' for #<Class:0x8aaa264> (NoMethodError)
```

what gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working because that method is not provided by `ActiveRecord`.

Perhaps you want `FastGrowers.find_or_create_by_id`?

```
grower = FastGrowers.find_or_create_by_id(t.id)
grower.update_attributes(:ticker => ticker, :five_year_growth_rate => growth_rate)
```

---

But if you have an `id`, you should know if you have a record, right? Hard to tell what you are trying to do, but something there is fishy.

Comment: yeah it is a little fishy i guess. I want this to work the first (when the table is empty) and every subsequent time. Also, yeah I thought it was part of active record.

Comment: @Ramy the truth is out there !

Comment: @oldergod All of which are private methods. It's not part of the public API.